# Two level domain suffix completion on a mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, dns, resolve

In Ubuntu, I have this line present in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
search example.com uk.example.com se.example.com
```

Now when I type `host svr1.uk` I get the record for svr1.uk.example.com
If I `ping svr1.uk`, I see pings from svr1.uk.example.com.

However, If I try to `ping svr1.uk` on a mac with the same `search` line present in /etc/resolv.conf I get `"ping: cannot resolve svr1.uk: Unknown host"` although I do see the record for srv1.uk.example.com from the `host` command.

Does any one have a way to make whichever lookup method `ping` uses properly resolve the domain suffixes in the order presented in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work for El Capitan anymore. If you upgrade to El Capitan you need to do this:

1. `defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist AlwaysAppendSearchDomains -bool true`
2. Reboot

See the mDNSResponder man page for more details.

Answer (score 2):

OSX does not use /etc/resolv.conf for DNS configuration. Instead check out [networksetup](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html).

To set the search domains:

```
sudo networksetup -setsearchdomains <network-interface> example.com uk.example.com se.example.com
```

To list the network interfaces/services:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Answer (score 0):

**On OS X 10.7-8**

Look for these lines (Around line 16; 10.8 starts around line 17), and add the third line on the end, then save the file

```
<string>/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder</string>
<string>-launchd</string>
<string>-AlwaysAppendSearchDomains</string>
```

**On OS X 10.9**

This is still around line 17 and will need to be re-edited after an OS upgrade.  The "-launchd" line won't exist, so just append the `alwaysappend` line.

Restart the responder:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

**On OS X 10.10.1**

The file is now called `com.apple.discoveryd.plist`, and you need to add a very similar item below the `ProgramArguments` tag. Add in `<string>--AlwaysAppendSearchDomains</string>` (note, there are *two* hyphens) to the items in the  tag. Run a similar pair of load/unload commands but referencing this new plist